# Can't serve file with json properly

Tags: json, node.js, image, response

```
var base64Img = require('base64-img');
var url = "http://home/asim/Desktop/MEAN/fb/public/images/"+req.session.user+".jpeg";
base64Img.requestBase64(url, function(err, res, body) {
console.log(res);     //prints undefined
console.log(body);    //prints undefined
console.log(url);     //prints url
});
```

The url being printed is "http://home/asim/Desktop/MEAN/fb/public/images/asim.jpeg" which is the exact url of the picture that I want to send along with my json data.
My directory structure is :-

```
--fb
----app.js(server running here)
----server(contains routes and models)
----client(contains .html with angular code)
----public
------images
--------asim.jpeg
```

What to do to send the image along with json response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is your image *isn't* being served from `http://home/asim/...` - or if it is, shouldn't be.

Given your processing this image on your server, you'll need to supply the absolute file path to the image

```
var url = `${__dirname}/public/images/${req.session.user}.jpeg`
```

Comment: Still no luck, It says now "Not allowed to load local resource:" .

Comment: @AsimRaja you need to be a little more specific, what says that? Do you have a full error stack? Post that.

Comment: The front end where I am putting the address of my img i.e. "file://home/asim/Desktop/MEAN/fb/public/images/asim.jpeg". When I put it in <img src=""> It says Not allowed to load local resource. You may have done sending images as response plis tell me briefly how to do that if images are stored locally in a server folder.

Comment: @AsimRaja well that's the issue - I thought your code was running at the _server_, not the client (this is why you should be specific with details in your question). Are you using Express by any chance? If so look at setting up a [static route](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) to let your server serve the image, then on the client you can request via `http` again.

Comment: @AsimRaja `.jpeg` is there because that's what you have in your file structure. Bare in mind this is working because your client will be on, and have access to, the same file structure as your server. This won't work if or when you actually host your site, consider looking at the static route setup I've linked you to in the previous comment.

Comment: so to make it work in real hosting what should I do? Change path or what?